# how to extract data from xml file using notepad++?

Tags: xml, notepad++

I have a xml response with a structure ( e.g groups > subgroups > child records ).

I want to extract list of all childRecord.name as separate data. I was hoping i can do something quick in notepad++ and then paste the results in excel.

I am not sure how to go about writing a macro may be in this case that would do this for me.

```
<group>

  <subgroup>

    <childrecord name="abc">zzz</childrecord>

  </subgroup>

</group>
```

Comment: While I don't have an answer for your question, I do have to thank you for causing me to discover http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/.

Answer (score 25):

Open the XML file with MS Excel directly.

## Update

From [support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-XML-data-6eca3906-d6c9-4f0d-b911-c736da817fa4#bmimport_an_xml_file_as_an_xml_list_wit):

> **Import an XML data file as an XML table**
>
> 1. Click Developer > Import.
>
>    If you don't see the Developer tab, see [Show the Developer tab](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-XML-data-6eca3906-d6c9-4f0d-b911-c736da817fa4#_ShowDeveloperTab).
> 2. In the Import XML dialog box, locate and select the XML data file (.xml) you want to import, and click Import.
>
>    If the XML data file doesn't refer to a schema, Excel infers the schema from the XML data file.
> 3. In the Import Data dialog box, do one of the following:
>
>    a. Select XML table in existing worksheet to import the contents of the XML data file into an XML table in your worksheet at the specified cell location.
>
>    b. Select XML table in new worksheet to import the contents of the file into an XML table in a new worksheet starting at cell A1. The schema of the XML data file is displayed in the XML Source task pane.
> 4. If the XML data file doesn't refer to a schema, then Excel infers the schema >from the XML data file.
> 5. To control the behavior of XML data (such as data binding, format, and layout), click Properties, which displays the XML Map properties dialog box. For example, existing data in a mapped range will be overwritten when you import data by default, but you can change this.

**Import XML file in LibreOffice Calc:**

1. From the menu bar, go to `Data` > `XML Source...`
2. Click on the browse button (folder icon) and choose the file from the dialog
3. Select the desired node
4. Fill the `Mapped cell` field for example `A1`
5. Click on <kbd>Import</kbd> button.

Comment: expand your answer please... how can I import and parse XML file in excel?

Comment: @infografik, I haven't used Windows for three years, but I believe that you can open the file with MS Excel as well as LibreOffice Calc.

Comment: well, You can open it, but it will be magically formatted and presented in any logical/structural view... just bunch of text..

Comment: Slightly disagree. This solution requires MS Office or Libre.

Answer (score 1):

Simply follow these steps:

1. Open your XML file with Notepad++
2. Select all text
3. Use this menu: [TextFX](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/TextFX/) -> TextFX Convert -> Strip HTLM tags table tabs/nontabs

Answer (score 0):

Maybe play with [PowerShell](https://techgenix.com/reading-extracting-xml-files-with-powershell/)'s "[Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.2)" instead of NotePad++